# Endianness and shift operator in C language, am I doing it correctly?

Tags: c, endianness, bit-shift

The original code works fine, it is :

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  while(readPortAPin1() == BAIXO);
  writePortAPin2(value & 0x01);
  value >>= 1;
  while(readPortAPin1() == ALTO);
}
```

In the first code, if value = 10101010 it will be sent as 01010101.
I would like to change the order of transmission, for example, if value = 10101010, I woul like to transmit 10101010.

To implement this, I did the following code:

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  while(readPortAPin1() == BAIXO);
  writePortAPin2(value & 0x80);
  value <<= 1;
  while(readPortAPin1() == ALTO);
}
```

But, it is not working, it is transmiting all 0s. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: if `value` is b10101010 and you want to send b10101010, you don't need to change it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with endianness. How is `value` declared?

Comment: I suspect that yoy need to write to the bottom bit of the port so try replacing `writePortAPin2(value & 0x80);` with `writePortAPin2((value & 0x80) >> 7);`

Comment: @Dipstick, maybe you are correct. I'll try as soon as I can, I'll post the result later

Comment: @Dipstick, I really need to write to the bottom bit of the port. When I did, it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `writePortAPin2()` writes the least significant bit of the operand. You need to write the most significant bit of `value`

Change this

```
writePortAPin2(value & 0x80);
```

to this

```
writePortAPin2((value >> 7) & 0x01);
```